# Is catkin recommended for use outside of ROS?

Tags: catkin, ubuntu, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm going through the exercise of setting up a new project that needs to be combined with other build-from-source pieces, and dealing with many of the same issues catkin was designed to solve: dependency, packaging, finding, etc.

So, my questions are:

- Is it easy to use catkin with non-ros
  projects?
- Are there any ros-specific
  pieces which will make this
  difficult?
- Is there a plan to move
  catkin out into the wider
  debian/ubuntu ecosystem / into official apt repositories?

  - I know
    python-catkin, and python-bloom
    already are

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/132596/is-catkin-recommended-for-use-outside-of-ros?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2014-02-24

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

catkin is 100% ROS agnostic. All ROS specific environment variables and settings are setup as hooks into catkin, so that catkin does not depend on ROS.

catkin has been used in non-ROS projects and can be run with only these dependencies:

- CMake
- Python
- catkin_pkg (python library for catkin)

Other tools have varying degrees of ROS integration.

`rosdep` is used to convert dependency names listed in the `package.xml` into calls to the system package manager. For example, `rosdep` will convert `boost` to `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` on ubuntu and to `brew install boost` on OS X.

`bloom` will generate Debian debs and (as of very recently) Fedora rpms for you, in a ROS agnostic way, but a lot of the features in bloom are ROS specific and github.com specific.

Other tools like catkin_simple do use some ROS specific stuff, but generally can be used without.

As for distribution. Currently we are still working towards a version of catkin which can be easily distributed through Debian proper, but it isn't a huge priority because you can easily bootstrap your build with catkin by just putting catkin's source code into your workspace.

You might even be able to see catkin in this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qe10ExwzCqk&t=2m8s

EDIT: More details have been posted here: http://osrfoundation.org/blog/project-tango-announced.html

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2014-02-25**:
Is there a guide for bootstrapping with catkin?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-02-25**:
You just checkout catkin into your workspace, along with your other packages.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

William Woodall recently mentioned [1] successfully using catkin for a non-ROS project, in particular he was using (the unreleased but seemingly usable) catkin_simple [2]. I'm sure @William can elaborate on the other questions.

- [1] https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ros-sig-buildsystem/7rBnq2bXIlo/IFhGYXLX-0gJ
- [2] https://github.com/catkin/catkin_simple

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-02-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1